# Is it possible to cover an icon this much of a shape in Android

Tags: android, android-drawable

I use layer-list to create button shape and add image

**myshape.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
            <solid android:color="#FDD400"/>
            <corners android:radius="15dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:src="@drawable/buy_card_24dp"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I add this `myshape.xml` as the background resource of an appcompact `button` using an `adapter` class since this `button` is in `gridview`

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_view_item, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.menuName);
        AppCompatButton appCompatButton = (AppCompatButton) v.findViewById(R.id.menuImage);
        appCompatButton.setBackgroundResource(menuList.get(position).getMenuImage());
        textView.setText(menuList.get(position).getMenuName());
        return v;

    }
```

and i specify the `myshape.xml` file in the main `class` like

```
ArrayList<MenuGridItem> menuList=new ArrayList<>();
        menuList.add(new MenuGridItem("Home",R.drawable.myshape));
```

but the icon in the `button` is too small and is it possible to cover the icon some percent of the shape

Answer (score 0):

I was using 24dp material icon now i changed to 48dp...now icon size is almost ok...